# keep worktrees/branches in sync with master after every commit

Tags: git, automation, git-worktree

I´m banging my head against hooks and worktrees at the moment.

My goal is to merge "main" into all worktrees whenever I do a commit on any branch.

So when I commit on "main", every branch merges the change.

When I commit on any other branch, it instantly merges "main" to prevent conflicts. Other Branches try to merge but are already up to date.

So i tried

.git/hooks/post-commit

```
#!/bin/sh    
for BRANCH in $(ls .git/refs/heads) 
do      
    git checkout $BRANCH #fatal: is already checked out
    git switch $BRANCH #same error
    git merge main
    git commit $BRANCH
done    
exit 0
```

how do I switch the Branch to make the merge and commit?

Thanks for your help

*edit*
The problem I want to solve is:
I do have 5-10 pretty obscure, undocumented, config files that need a common body (main) that is splat all over the place and then add/alter some lines/values for the specific device. It seems to be somewhat sensitive to the ordering of Options. Some I can move around some result in error messages ("unexpected parameter in line xy").

Changes are made in main as well as in the branches.

I thought its easier to do the merge always and on any branch (without effect) than automate it to do it only on specific branches.

So functional its equivalent to:

- Commit main: Merge to all
- Commit branch01: Merge main to branch01 (to create a new state to prevent conflicts).

My worktrees are remote branches, sorry for the confusion. I´m new to git and struggling with the lingo.

I did get conflicts when I created line 1 "special to branch01" in Branch 01, commit. Then add "something I need in every config" on Main line1 commit. The merge results in a conflict, because both changes are "add line 1 X/Y"

Comment: This statement doesn't make sense to me: "My goal is to merge "main" into all worktrees whenever I do a commit on any branch." (Did you mean "branches" instead of "worktrees" there?) And, unless `main` changed since the last time you committed, merging it in again would have no effect. Also, the next statement doesn't make practical sense to me, but at least it's logical, "So when I commit on "main", every branch merges the change." You could do that part if you really want to (though I wouldn't do "all branches", maybe just certain special branches that need it?).

Comment: Also, what is the problem you're actually trying to solve? You mentioned, "When I commit on any other branch, it instantly merges "main" to prevent conflicts." But what's to say you won't get conflicts on that automated merge?

Comment: In scripts to list all branches , use `git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:short)"` instead of `ls .git/refs/heads`. `.git/refs/heads` does not contain packed refs.

Comment: This looks like an incredible overcomplication judging by the fact that you are trying to `git switch` and merge in a post-commit hook.